# Recursive formulas and integration

Tags: calculus, integration, recursion

Using integration by parts find a recursive formula of $\int cos^n(x) dx$ and use it to find $\int cos^5 x dx$

I have no idea how to do this and my knowledge does include integration by parts etc. I just do not know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: So far all i have done is try to integrate $Cos^{n-1}(x)*Cos(x) dx$

Comment: Different question considering i'm given the required method of calculating and the other question isn't.

Comment: Look carefully, see the $cos^n(x)$ part, there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they give you the trick (integration by parts), let us try $$u=\cos^{n-1}(x)\quad dv=\cos(x) \,dx$$ So, $$du=-(n-1)\cos^{n-2}(x)\,\sin(x)\,dx \quad  v=\sin(x)$$ So, $$I_n=\int \cos^n(x)\,dx=\cos^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\,\sin^2(x)\,dx$$ But $$\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\,\sin^2(x)\,dx=\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\,(1-\cos^2(x))\,dx=\int \cos^{n-2}(x)\,dx-\int \cos^{n}(x)\,dx$$ So, finally $$I_n=\cos^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)+(n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_n)$$

Isolate $I_n$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just one question, what does the $I$ represent/stand for?

Comment: It is just to put a name : $I_n=\int \cos^n(x)\,dx$

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, Thanks a lot

Comment: You are very welcome !

Comment: If you are not busy and feel like doing more maths i have another question elsewhere on the site which i'm deeply struggling with. [Click Here :D](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516872/falling-object-physics-calculus)
It's differential equations, integration and motion. Thanks again!

Comment: Chinny84 gave a simple solution. Where is your problem with it ?

Comment: It wasn't explained well so i don't understand a lot of the differential calculus method he has used at all. I've been trying to understand it but it seems there has been a lot of small steps missed which add up to me and i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I think it is good work. It makes a problem to me to clarify Chinny84 's answer in your previous post. Ask him explaining where you are stuck. He/she will answer, I am sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31214/discussion-between-brayden-and-claude-leibovici).